# simple_form_for, having label and input on the same line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

When i create a form with simple_form_for, it puts the label and below the input, like the following:

name
***_*_**

But i want them to be:

name ***_*_**

If i look at the html generated, i see:

```
<div class="input string optional name">
    <label class="string optional" for="name">date from</label>
    <input class="string optional" id="name" name="anf[name]" size="50" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

but I don't understand where, in the style, there is the setting that makes it to break the line; here it is the computed style:

```
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
display: block;
font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: 65px;
line-height: 18px;
width: 940px;
```

Anyway, is there a way to customize this appearance of simple_form_for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a SimpleForm example I've used where the label and the input are on the same line...

HTML

```
<%= simple_form_for(@proteam) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :city %>
  <%= f.input :mascot %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

CSS

```
.simple_form label {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 2px 10px;
}

.simple_form div.input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

This essentially comes from http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form-revised

Comment: OK, but with float:left, if I have more controls on the same line, say (label-1) (field-1) (label-2) (field-2) ALL THE LABEL COLLAPSE TOGETHER at the begininning of the line: (label-1)(label-2)(field-1)(field-2). aaagh! it's not what i wanted. replaced with display: inline-block; hate the trial-and-errors approach.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's the rule

```
display: block;
```

Change it to

```
display: inline
```

to prevent the label from breaking the line.

Comment: Ok, but where is it in the SimpleForm architecture?

Comment: I don't think simple_form adds css for you, so I guess you inherited that code from some framework?